# Need guidance to simplify this query

Tags: sql, hive, query-optimization, hiveql

We have a huge query with many conditions.
However, we feel that some of the conditions are irrelevant
can you please let me know if `where` clause here, can be removed

Please find below excerpt of the huge query ( the sub-query) with `where` clause

```
SELECT f1,  ... f10 
FROM A
JOIN
SELECT f1, f2 ... f10
FROM B where PROC_DT IN (SELECT PROC_DATE FROM C)
ON A.ID = B.ID
WHERE ISNOTNULL(PROC_DT)
```

I think the query will already validate the PROC_DATE in getting data from table B. so can we remove the `where` clause here.

Can someone please confirm my findings

Comment: *I think the query will already validate the PROC_DATE in getting data from table B* how can anyone know that? You are the one who has access to the actual data.

Comment: @forpas of course you can -- it can't be null because of  `PROC_DT IN (SELECT PROC_DATE FROM C)`

Comment: @Hogan there are 2 where clauses here. To which are you referring and to which is the OP referring? Which where can or can't be removed?

Comment: @forpas the where is not null statement -- that was implied where he said (in just the sentence before) it will already validate because it is getting the data from b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you are correct, because of the in it can't be null.  I would use an inner join instead, in some cases it will be faster.

```
SELECT f1,  ... f10 
FROM A
JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID
join (SELECT DISTINCT PROC_DATE FROM C) AS X ON B.PROC_DT = X.PROC_DATE
```